# How to show items in a many2one field based on user group in odoo-9?

Tags: odoo-9

I have a many2one field and I want to show the items in it based on the logged in user's group. I am using odoo-9.

Answer (score 0):

add a many2many to res.group in the co_model of the many2one field than do a domain on the field m2o to show the records based on the many2many field

model --- man2one --> co_model --- many2many ---> res.group

than put a domain to the many2one field based on the the group of the user